# Get an object assigned in HTML file with Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to use cypress to interact with a JS library that renders a user interface to the DOM. The user interacts with the library through an instance of an object that represents the GUI.

```
let editor = new Formr.Editor(...);
```

The above line is in a `<script>` tag in the index.html page. I am calling `cy.visit(./index.html)` and the page loads fine, but using `cy.wrap(editor)` complains about `editor` being undefined.

Th reason I need to access the `editor` instance is to check it's state after interacting with the DOM.

How can I access `editor` from within cypress?

**Update: Richard's suggestion**

So I've tried this:

index.html:
`const editor = window.editor = new Formr.Editor(...)`

Cypress test:

```
it("Should add a row when clicked", () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:63342/formr');

    const editor = cy.state('window').editor;

    cy.get("#feditor-add-row-button")
    .click();

    cy.wrap(editor)
        .invoke('Data')
        .its('rows')
        .should('eq', 1);
});
```

Unfortunately it still doesn't seemt to work. Is cypress smart enough to wait for `window` to be `ready`?

Answer (score 1):

Within the script tag you can set a reference to `editor` on window,

```html
<script>
  let editor = new Formr.Editor(...);
  window.editor = editor;
```

then in the test grab it

```js
const editor = cy.state('window').editor;`.
```

For more details, see [Testing Vue web applications with Vuex data store & REST backend](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2017/11/28/testing-vue-web-application-with-vuex-data-store-and-rest-backend/#store-testing) where Vuex is added to window to make it accessible in the tests.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. See my edit. Also, I can't seem to find `state` anywhere in the cypress docs, and my IDE complains it's undefined... Are you sure it exists?

Comment: This works fine for me. cy.state() is used in lot's of places, e.g code coverage add-on. There's a pull request for documentation, but until accepted expect the api may change.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `.its` combined with Richard Matsen's suggestion to assign the `editor` to a `window` variable.

```
cy.window()
    .its('editor.rows.length')
    .should('equal', 2);
```